# Iterating Through azure SQL table in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF 2 and trying to grapple with the web activity.

The tasks are.

Copy file from blob storage and put the data in an azure SQL database
Iterate through the data and use a PUT call to a REST API to update the data

Okay so I can get the data in the table no problem. I can also make the call using a Web activity to the the API and put some hard coded data there.

But I've been trying to use a For Each to iterate through the table I have and call the web activity to pass that data to the API

This is where I'm stuck. I'm New to data factory and been through all their standard help information but not getting any where.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hey Steve, I am stuck at the same thing. Did you use 'Execute Pipeline' and execute the web activity in the child pipeline?

Comment: That's what I wanted to try and do but can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to drive the foreach via a SQL lookup task that populates a data set and then call the activity for each row:

here are some posts to get you started:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity

replace the copy activity with the web call in the tutorial below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal

Comment: Hi, I was looking for someone who has done and give guidance. the online tutorials aren't helping me